# Why did my IDE related question get downvoted/flagged?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have posted several questions about programming specifics which never have a problem and are often well-received and answered, but as someone new to XCode I have been asking for help with fixing certain things within the IDE and often receive downvotes or close votes. For example, I posted this question this afternoon:

[Swift Language Version Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356630/swift-language-version-error)

I got a close vote for not specifying code when the question has nothing to do with my specific code or desired output. I am curious as to how to write these questions better or an explanation of why these are inappropriate for SO.

Comment: Either post the picture inlined, or even better post the verbatim error text. That's probably the culprit for the downvotes.

Comment: Also include which similar answers you already checked/tried so users can verify you picked the right solution(s)

Comment: Modified the language here.  This is centric to your question and not other IDE-related questions.

Comment: @Makoto Honestly the fact that the question is an IDE question isn't even relevant.  The question didn't contain enough information to reproduce and understand the problem.  That's not unique to IDE questions at all.

Comment: @Servy:  Well no, not at all.  I don't disagree there.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception do me a fav and read that, as it covers a number of points. I'm interested in feedback, too.

Answer (score 10):

I am the person who voted to close the question. The close reason states (emphasis added):

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem **or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

You don't necessarily have to have any specific code for this close reason to apply.

Xcode is showing you an error and you posted a picture of it instead of including it as text in your question. This makes it both unsearchable for anyone else who has the same problem and extremely hard to read (even for people on a desktop - let alone anyone who is on a mobile version of the site). Since this was also pointed out in a comment by the time I saw the question I didn't see a reason to add an explanation for my close vote.

Also, you could generally still add more information to the question. Currently, I can only assume that the code is written in Swift 3 based on the fact that your friend doesn't see this error and that he is running the latest Xcode version. Is that true? Either way it would be helpful to directly include this kind of information in the question as well so that anyone trying to help won't have to make educated guesses about your exact situation.

Adding a specific version of Xcode wouldn't be too bad either. While it might not be necessary at the moment (because it is clear what the currently latest version of Xcode is) it could be useful for anyone in the future who encounters the same issue and is running a (by then) old version of Xcode.

Edit: I wrote *"because it is clear what the currently latest version of Xcode is"* but thinking about it again made me realize that it's actually not clear at all. There's a current latest stable version (Xcode 8.3.3) and then there's the "latest latest" version which would be whatever beta they're at right now for Xcode 9. This could very well be the cause for that error, so you should definitely add that information to the question.

Comment: *and extremely hard to read* - Not to mention impossible for anyone who's company firewall prevents the image from loading and anyone relying on a screen reader. The alt text of "Picture of error screen" was basically useless. (rene's edit solved that issue)

Comment: Totally fair, I didn't understand the issue with the picture, but I really do not know anymore about how to ask the other aspects of the question

Comment: @JoshKopen I'm not really sure what exactly you mean by "the other aspects of the question"? Are you talking about the additional information I'm asking you to add?

Comment: I guess the biggest issue is that I add things I've checked in the question and clearly don't know what to add next. I don't view it as an incomplete question and the inherent issue is the lack of knowledge about what to add, because if I knew I would have solved the problem myself. I guess my point is that I feel it is more appropriate to comment and ask for clarification rather than the downvote or close vote.